# Poor JS performance on Firefox and Midori

Tags: applications

I just installed fresh elementary OS Freya as my new web development (Node.js) environment. I updated the system, upgraded it and installed NVIDIA GeForce drivers (the tested ones, not -updates).

Problem is the performance of browsers. Firefox is lagging on scrolling (on some webpages that are JS heavy) and overall JS performance is terrible. Agar.io not playable due to low FPS on a machine with i3 3220 and GeForce GTX460 and 8GB of RAM. What could be a reason for such problems?

Apart from that system is snappy and pages that don't rely heavily on real-time JS are just fine (SO for example).

Comment: have you tried chrome??

Comment: I tried Opera (Chromium pretty much). It works way better but the web dev tools are rather meh compared to Firefox...

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems as if the problems went away after installing npm and node. Firefox runs just fine now and I can't really reproduce the earlier state.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling graphics hardware acceleration:

`Edit` > `Preferences` > `Advanced Tab` > `General`

You should find the `Use hardware acceleration when available` checkbox. Uncheck this checkbox, restart Firefox and see what happens.